# DJI Simulation software for Linux without physical drone

Tags: dji, simulators

I need a software for linux, that can connect to a DJI Remote control (RM500) via USB, and can send simulated GPS data to the RC.

Normally, DJI says, that you need a physical drone present to access the saves PID controller values to accurately mimic the Drone. However, in this case, I **only** need something that just sends me FAKE BUT PLAUSIBLE GPS data (may be battery data), so that an MSDK app can read this data. This is intended only for test.

I need the system to preferably run on linux, and be able to simulate WITHOUT a physical drone. Thank you

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.